# Double-click instead of single-click for custom SObject checkbox

Tags: visualforce, custom-field

I have the following Visualforce page in the Contacts page layout:

[image]

A single click will, as expected, toggle the checkbox selection and update the SObject field value. This is all good. However, I want to be able to change the checkbox value on a double-click, not on a single click. Something like how the same custom SObject checkbox behaves when otherwise used directly on the SF page layout (versus on a VF page) would also be nice:

[image]

Here is my VF page code for the SObject checkbox:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
<!-- first row -->
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contact}" var="c"> 
         <apex:column headerValue="On Approved List" width="111">
            <apex:inputField value="{!c.EJF_On_Approved__c}"> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="theBlock" action="{!saveRecord}"/> 
            </apex:inputfield>
        </apex:column>
```

Suggested changes to the code if provided as complete code would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the possible ways to do this is use of [`apex:inlineEditSupport`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm) for the checkbox. However you need to to use the `apex:outputField` instead of `apex:inputField`:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contact}" var="c"> 
    <apex:column headerValue="On Approved List" width="111">
    <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_On_Approved__c}"> 
        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                                hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                                changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="theBlock" action="{!saveRecord}"/> 
    </apex:outputField>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks mastOr for your response. Before I go ahead and try this, quick question: isn't the <apex:outputField> read-only?

Comment: So I tried inline support using a simplified version                                <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_On_Approved__c}"> 
       <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/></apex:outputfield>                                              However, I am not able to change the checkbox selection because I believe <apex:outputField> is acting strictly read-only.

Comment: @Rosh Not read-only with inlineEditSupport! If inEdit is active the field will be shows as read-only, but on double click it will be editable. Try to reproduce the doc example, you will see that this is a nice feature:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm Important: don't forget to use `<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">`

Comment: MastOr, your solution partially works. Also, please recall the saveRecord method you gave me in an earlier question I had asked, which worked absolutely fine. Using your saveRecord method, I was able to update the user's checkbox selection. That was a huge help. Now, for the current issue, it seems like both the inlineEditSupport event AND the actionSupport event are both not getting fired. I essentially want the custom saveRecord action to be triggered when the checkbox is toggled. So I updated the button action to fire saveRecord instead of the standard save fuctionality.

Comment: So now when user clicks the custom save button, the checkbox selection is remembered. However, if I can somehow get the saveRecord to be fired without the save button, just like any standard checkbox field is updated on a page layout...that is precisely what I need. Saving on a single click (not by hitting a button) was earlier taken care of by the actionSupport action firing away saveRecord but now with the intro of inlineEditSupport, can I execute saveRecord only with a button? Can't I update checkbox selection like a std checkbox field that doesn't have a button for update? Please help.